# Multiple layers in one ggplot2 stat_ function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a new `stat_` function for ggplot2 with the possibility to return multiple layers with some transformations of the ordinate `y` variable. My problem is that I have one function that computes multiple transformations with a long time computation and I want to perform the computation only once.
Here one example: `long_function` returns a data.frame with 5 statistics m1, m2, m3, m4 and m5:

```r
long_function <- function(x) {
    data.frame(m1 = x * 1, m2 = x * 2, m3 = x * 3, m4 = x * 4, m5 = x * 5)
}
```

I want to create a `stat_` function that plots one or several m statistics. I’ve tried something like that but I only manage to plot one m statistic (and I want to do the computation only once, so I don't want to call `stat_longfunction()` several times) :

```r
library(ggplot2)
StatLongFunction <- ggproto("StatLongFunction", Stat, 
                            required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                            compute_group = function(data, scales,
                                                     component = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5")) {
                                component <- match.arg(component,several.ok = TRUE)
                                result_longf <- long_function(data$y)
                                data$y <- result_longf[,component[1]]
                                cbind(data,result_longf)
                            }
)

stat_longfunction <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "line",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                              inherit.aes = TRUE,
                              component = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5"),
                              ...) {
    layer(
        stat = StatLongFunction, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
        params = list(component = component, ...)
    )
}

p <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    stat_longfunction(colour = "red", component = "m3") 
p
```

[image]

I’ve tried to write a new `geom_` function but I don't think this is the better solution here (and my code doesn’t seem satisfying):

```r
GeomLongFunction <- ggproto("GeomLongFunction", Geom,
                            required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                            default_aes = aes(
                                colour = NA, fill = "grey20", size = 0.5,
                                linetype = 1, alpha = 1
                            ),
                            draw_key = draw_key_abline,

                            draw_group = function(data, panel_params, coord,
                                                  component = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5")) {
                                component <- match.arg(component, several.ok = TRUE)
                                result_grob <- lapply(component,function(comp){
                                    data_comp <- data
                                    data_comp$y <- data[,comp]
                                    coords <- coord$transform(data_comp, panel_params)
                                    grid::linesGrob(
                                        coords$x, coords$y, 
                                        default.units = "native",
                                        gp = grid::gpar(
                                            col = coords$colour,
                                            lwd = coords$size * .pt,
                                            lty = coords$linetype
                                        )
                                    )
                                })
                                do.call(grid::gList, result_grob)
                            }
)
geom_longfunction <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "long_function",
                              position = "identity", show.legend = NA, 
                              inherit.aes = TRUE,
                              component = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5"), ...) {
    layer(
        geom = GeomLongFunction, mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
        params = list(component = component, ...)
    )
}
p <- ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_longfunction(colour = "red", component = c("m3","m2")) 
p
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A short answer of the top of my head: return the results of the long computations as a tidy data.frame: one column for all results together with a factor indexing by computation name. This will allow grouping, and plotting using a single call to a geom. As long as you intend to use the same geom for all computed values, this is the simples approach. Add a parameter to the stat to pass a vector for indexing/subsetting the returned data.frame within the stat.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand well your suggestion: I tried to change the output of the `compute_group` function to return the tidy table but I didn't succeed to do the grouping. I for example tried, unsuccessfully, to add a new parameter to `aes()`. How would you do it?